# Why can't i generate a oauth2 discord link

Tags: oauth-2.0, discord

The select redirect uri button isnt clickable:

[image: The select redirect uri button isnt clickable]

I tried to generate an discord oauth2 link, but i cant do it because discord doesnt allow me to select the redirect uri. I specified the redirect uri but there is still nothing

I did everything reloaded the site, created new applications, entered from a new profile, but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

You need to select an redirect URI.

here is a simple guide I made to do that:

> *1. add a redirect URI to the Redirects list*

[image: 1]

> *2. Save this first before trying to generate the link or it will not work*

[image: 2]

> *3. Now select your scopes and the URI you want to redirect to and your generated URL should show up in the generated URL box*

[image: 3]

I hope this helped!

Comment: The dropdown menu was blocked by a chrome extension i used, so everything is fine